# Подсчет суммы при нажатии кнопки Delphi7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Как поставить изначальное значение sumComp, sumHum на ноль, сейчас при каждом нажатии на кнопку выводятся большие числа(<16000)

```
  procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
   var hDice, cDice:shortint;
   sumComp, sumHum: integer;

  begin
  Randomize;
  hDice :=random(6);
  cDice :=random(6);
  Label1.Caption := IntToStr(hDice+1);
  Label2.Caption := IntToStr(cDice+1);
  ...
  sumComp := sumComp+cDice;
  sumHum := sumHum+hDice;
  Label6.Caption:=IntToStr(sumComp);
```

Comment: Присваивать им 0 пробовали?

Comment: При каждом нажатии на кнопку sumComp будет присваивать ему 0, а мне нужно только при запуске программы

Comment: Ну сделайте переменные  `sumComp`, `sumHum` полями класса